# How to stress memory on web server?

Tags: memory, web, jmeter, load, stress-testing

I have created web cluster with several web sites and I would like to perform stress test of a memory but I have no clue how to.... I have used Jmeter but I always get CPU load not memory (cant used more then 1GB). Is there anyway to stress test it by Jmeter?

p.s. I would like to avoid custom scripts because I want my test to be repeatable by anyone. For websites I am using generic WP installations.

Comment: Did you play with the "Thred group" configuration ? I think setting a high number of Threads should increase memory usage. And if not, maybe you app just don't really need memory but only CPU. It can be true if they are only few object but large amount of computation.

Comment: I did all combinations and cant stress memory enough.... cpu goes up to 20 cores and memory less then 1GB (20 WP portals).

Comment: Ok, so you app seems just to need few amount of memory... If you want to write good performance test, is not really usefful to try to overload your memory. Just estimate the maximum number number of concurrent user and the duration of this. For exemple, if your app must work with maximum of 100 user on one hour, test it with 150 on 2 hours ;)

Comment: Already tried that, memory look like its "locked" on 50% (600Mb) and it will not go over what ever I do... If I define longer test or more users CPU only suffers. I need to stress memory so I can test another thing and that is "automatic memory relocation" (adding extra memory). But I cant get scenario so I can need more memory...

Comment: I think the only thing you can do in your case is reduce the amount of available memory. If your test need 1G0, set your server to use a maximum of half of that, i.e, 500Mo.  
Because if your application do not need a lot of memory, you cannot force it to use more...